# How do I remove a partition from a write-protected USB drive?

Tags: usb-flash-drive, write-protect

Just got this USB drive as a freebie.
It has two partitions, and only one is write protected ... so it's not a switch.
Tried EnableUSBWrite.reg
And tried reformatting from cmd.
Diskpart doesn't list the drive.
Suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [I have a password protected USB drive with hidden partition, how to convert to normal USB drive?](http://superuser.com/questions/34729/i-have-a-password-protected-usb-drive-with-hidden-partition-how-to-convert-to-n)

Comment: thanks techie but that thread didn't help me. I tried the hp tool and the drive isn't listed when I run diskpart

Answer (score 0):

Try a third party partitioning software, like  Minitool partition wizard or the like. It will show you all partitions on the thumb drive and you can manipulate or remove it.